# Swift Php Json Chinese Character

Tags: php, json, swift

I have both English and Chinese Character in my database, but when I retrieve in JSON the Chinese Character does not work. Result is "?". Anyone can help me ?

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
/* include db.config.php */
include_once("config.php");
// Get user id
$id = isset($_GET['username']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']) : “”;

if(empty($id)){
    $data = array ("result" => 0, "message" => 'Wrong user id');
} else {
// get user data
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT username, gender, location, birthday, mobilephone, signature FROM users WHERE username='$id'");

$data = array ();

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['username'] = $row['username'];
        $row_array['gender'] = $row['gender'];
        $row_array['location'] = $row['location'];
        $row_array['birthday'] = $row['birthday'];
        $row_array['mobilephone'] = $row['mobilephone'];
        $row_array['signature'] = $row['signature'];
        //push the values in the array
        array_push($data,$row_array);
 }
 echo json_encode($data);

mysql_close($conn);
/* JSON Response */
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your table fields collation are set to utf8-general-ci. Open your table -> Structure -> here check it. If it not, edit the field and change it. Now add new entry and check.

Comment: my table is set to utf8-general-ci. In my table I can see the data in Chinese Character, but when I use my PHP API to change it to JSON, my JSON result is not in UTF8 format. I think the problem is in the PHP Code

Comment: Place `echo '<pre>';print_r($data);` before `echo json_encode($data);` and check the output. Is it also returning question marks?

Comment: Try this echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Comment: I tried to add 'echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);' but I got the following error 'Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /home/paipai58/www/www/app/data/jsonpersodata.php on line 28'

Comment: What is your PHP version? Also make sure the variable $data returns array values and not empty.

Comment: My PHP Version is 5.4. The $data returns array values, because all the english character I can see it, I just can not see chinese character

Comment: Place echo '<pre>';print_r($data); before echo json_encode($data); and share the output.

Comment: 'Array ( [0] => Array ( [username] => myusername [gender] => ? [location] => ?? [birthday] => 1901/01/16 [mobilephone] => 136888888 [signature] => My name is myname  ) ) [{"username":"myusername ","gender":"?","location":"??","birthday":"1901\/01\/16","mobilephone":"136888888","signature":"My name is my name"}]' As you can see my "gender" and "location" is ?. it should be a chinese character instead

Comment: The array itself returns with ?. So there is a problem in fetching data. Place `$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC);echo '<pre>';print_r($row);` before `$data = array ();` and share the output.

Comment: [{"username":"myusername","gender":"?","location":"??","birthday":"1901\/01\/16","mobilephone":"138888888","signature":"My name is myname"}]

Comment: Don't remove the previous code. Just place the following code `mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET "utf8"');` after `// get user data` and share the output.

Comment: [{"username":"myusername","gender":"\u7537","location":"\u676d\u5dde","birthday":"1901\/01\/16","mobilephone":"138888888","signature":"My name is myname"}]

Comment: Please try `mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"');`. Also make sure, chinese characters or stored in table or in the format **\u7537**?

Comment: it is working now! Thanks a lot @Karthikeyani ! Any idea about this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675932/need-your-help-ios-swift-post-data-to-json-alamofire) no one answer me ....

Comment: I unable to find the variable $username in your code!! Also you are overwriting the $id value in 6th line. Is that variable will be $id or $username?