# Need your help, IOS Swift Post data to Json Alamofire

Tags: php, swift, alamofire

I have a textlbabelfield in which I get data from my external database through JSon. Now, I would like to let my user to modify this field and post it to the database. But again, it doesn't work, the database did not change. Please could you review my code:

PHP Code:

```
       <?php
/* include db.config.php */
include_once("config.php");
// Get user id
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) : “”;
$data = isset($_POST['signature']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['signature']) : “”;

// get user data
mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"');
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET signature = '$data' WHERE username='$username'");

die;
mysql_close($conn);
/* JSON Response */

?>
```

Alamofire post func:

```
    @IBAction func Signature(sender: UIButton) {
        var signaturesave1 = self.signature
        let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var username = prefs.valueForKey("USERNAME") as NSString
        //load and parse the JSON into an array
        Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://mywebsite/app/data/jsonsavesignature.php", parameters: ["username": username, "signature":signaturesave1]).responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                println("error calling GET usersdata")
                println(error)
            }
            else {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("signature_to_persoinfo", sender: self)
    }

        }
}
```

Comment: I unable to find the variable $username in your code!! Also you are overwriting the $id value in 6th line. Is that variable will be $id or $username?

Comment: Yes you are right, I have some problem in my variable. I edit my post but still does;t works. What I want to do is to change my signature for one specific username.

Comment: Replace `$sql = mysql_query("INSERT signature INTO users WHERE username='$username'");` with the following code and share the output `echo "INSERT signature INTO users WHERE username='$username'"; if(mysql_query("INSERT signature INTO users WHERE username='$username'")){echo 'inserted';}else{ echo mysql_error($conn);}die;`

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/website/www/www/app/data/jsonsavesignature.php:1) in /home/website/www/www/app/data/jsonsavesignature.php on line 3
INSERT signature INTO users WHERE username='鈥溾��'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO users WHERE username='鈥溾��'' at line 1. I got this code when in my browser I go to the following address: http://mywebsite/app/data/jsonsavesignature.php?username=myusername

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the answer, thanks to Karthikeyani for your help, I post the answer to share with everyone:

My PHP Script:

```
 <?php

/* include db.config.php */
include_once("config.php");
// Get user id
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) : “”;
$data = isset($_POST['signature']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['signature']) : “”;

// get user data
mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"');
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET signature = '$data' WHERE username='$username'");

mysql_close($conn);
/* JSON Response */

?>
```

my Alamofire post request:

```
  @IBAction func Signature(sender: UIButton) {
        var signaturesave1 = self.signature.text
        let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var username = prefs.valueForKey("USERNAME") as NSString
        let parameters =
            ["username": username, "signature":signaturesave1]

        //load and parse the JSON into an array
        Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://mywebsite.com/app/data/jsonsavesignature.php", parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in

                 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("signature_to_persoinfo", sender: self)

        }
    }
```

Comment: You removed if, else condition in **Alamofire post request** in the updated code right?

Comment: Yes and also the parameters in Alamofire were wrong I think. I am not sure my code is complete but it is working

Comment: This is not good because 1. You should have accepted Karthikeyani's answer rather than reposting it yourself. 2. The stuff that you added to Karthikeyani's answer is generally inadvisable, e.g. (a) you're checking neither the `$sql` return code or checking the number of affected rows; and (b) you're using mysql interface instead of mysqli or PDO (see [this discussion](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)).

Answer (score 2):

If you are updating the existing data then you need to use update query, not insert query. Insert query is to insert a new data. So replace `mysql_query("INSERT signature INTO users WHERE username='$username'");` with `mysql_query("UPDATE users SET signature = '$data' WHERE username='$username'");`, where $data is the signature of the user.

Comment: I edit my PHP Script. With your changes I can update the table. But the data in mysql is wrong. For example I add "my name is Charles" in signature, but the result in my database is : <UITextView: 0x7fe4b4853800; f. The second problem is when I run my APP it is now not working. I get in output: <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7fe4b3e42980> { URL: http://mywebsite/app/data/jsonsavesignature.php }

Comment: Let me know the variable which you want to update in table and the field name. Because currently you are updating signature field based on username field. But in your previous post, you have mentioned the username as a input. So what do you want to update in the table? And what will be the value for signature. Give an example. Also, remove the sample codes which I have provided in previous post except update query changes.

Comment: My table's name is: "users". I want to update "signature' field based on username field. Value for signature is varchar(30). For example: "I love Stackoverflow"

Comment: Place `echo $data; die;` before `if(empty($username)){` and share the output. Have you deleted all the sample code which provided previously? remove die, echo and print_r statements and check.

Comment: First of all thank you for your help. when I call this url: http://mywebsite/app/data/jsonsavesignature.php?username=myusername&signature=mynameischarlesThe result now is: 鈥溾�� Very strange. I am not sure if I remove all the code provided previously, I think so. Please check in my original post, I edited with my current code.

Comment: That's OK. What about the variable $username? replace `echo $data; die;` with `echo $username; die;`and let me know the output. Also you are not returning anything in this. But checking the ajax response in **Alamofire post func**. So check that too.

Comment: Still the same 鈥溾�� stuff. and in my Xcode output: <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7fa73146ebd0> { URL: http://mywebsite/app/data/jsonsavesignature.php }

Comment: So both username and signature returns the same value? but not updating the correct value in database?

Comment: yes, return same value. I add: "My name is Charles" in the signature field and the result in my mysql database is update to "<UITextView: 0x7fe4b4853800; f"

Comment: What is the reason to assign this  `array ("result" => 0, "message" => 'Wrong user id');` to variable **$username**? Are you going to return this value? Change the variable name and try once again. I'm not familiar with IOS application. I'm a web application developer. So try it. And remove echo,die too. Finally place `die;` before `mysql_close($conn);` and check the table. If the table updated successfully, then there must be problem in somewhere.

Comment: actually there is no reason to assign this array.... I don't need it. I only need to update "signature" that's it

Comment: If so, hide the code and place `die;` before `mysql_close($conn);` and check the table whether the field updated with correct value or not.

Comment: I again edit and update my code if you want to be sure I did as you mention. I erase the value of my signature field in my mysql, it is now empty. When I use the url in my browser like that: http://mywebsite/app/data/jsonsavesignature.php?username=myusername&signature=mynameischarles the result in my database still empty, it does not update the signature field

Comment: Change $_POST   to  $_REQUEST

Also,make sure that your table has the username "myusername".